# ionic ng-bind-html not parsing html from json data

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, ng-bind-html

I'm trying to display some text that is stored in a json data file. Since the text needs some basic formatting such as p tags I have coded them into the text as so:

```
[ { "htmlText": "<p>Here is some formatted text</p><p>This will be another para</p>" } ]
```

As I am using IONIC I have the following set up

```
//Add the ngSanitize 
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngSanitize'])
.controller('StuffController', ['$scope', '$state', '$http', function($scope, $state, $http) {
 $http.get('data/stuff.json').success(function(data){

 //function to pass the text with html coding
 $scope.sanitizeMe = function(text) { 
 return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)  
 };

$scope.stuff = data;

 });
}])
```

And I am using it in my template as so

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="text in stuff">
   <div ng-bind-html="sanitizeMe(text.htmlText)"></div>
</div>
```

As far as I can tell this should produce appropriately formatted text, however all I get is

```
<p>Here is some formatted text</p>This will be another para</p>
```

As can be seen the ng-bind-html is not working. I've checked many posts and all suggest that this should work. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone solve this for me?